# How Can I change OkHttpClient to AsyncTask

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask

OkHttpClient not work in my mainactivity.java. I want to use AsyncTask but I don't know how can I change it. I want to send

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

to my server.

There is my code with OkHttpClient. Thank you

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        registerToken(token);
        Log.d("TOKEN", token);
    }

    private void registerToken(String token){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Token", token)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://localhost/register.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `How Can I change OkHttpClient to AsyncTask`. Impossible. You cannot compare them. They are different things. The first is a http client. The latter a thread.  Please tell better what you want.

Comment: I want to send this daha FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() to my server without OkHttpClient

Comment: And? Any question rephrasing in sight?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AsyncTask Android example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: It is terrible how you formulate your question.  `I want to send

FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
to my server.'. But you ment: `"After i got a token string with  

String token =  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); i want to send string token 
to my server.". So irrelevant where the content came from. You just want to send a string.

Comment: That's my fault, I'm new on android. You are right. I want to send a string without OkHttpClient

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You'll have to send url to OkHttpAsync. Like new `OkHttpAsync().excute(url);`

```
public class OkHttpAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {



    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token", token)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(params[0])
            .post(body)
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request ).execute();
    return response.body().bytes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] b ) {
        //Handle result here
        super.onPostExecute(playlistListResponse);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is how you send url to the `OkHttpAsync` class and result will in onPostExcute method of OkHttpAsync class.

```
OkHttpAsync okHttpAsync = new OkHttpAsync();
okHttpAsync.execute("http://localhost/register.php");
```

EDIT 2.

I see you are having trouble with network request in android. Network request shouldn't be on mainThread. If you fire it on main Thread then it will cause exception. There are many libaraies for network requests in android. i would recommend you use Volley. Here is a [tutorial](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/), go through it.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you @ZeeshanShabbir I can't see  url for website on your code. I'm new on android, Can you give me full code, sorry for that

Comment: OP does not want to use OkHttpClient was what i understood. So i do not understand this answer.

Comment: OP didn't represent his question according to his needs. Question needs to go through edit.

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() this code gives me a token. I want to send this token to my server. I can send token with first code in my answer but I need to send token without OkHttpClient. Because OkHttpClient not work in mymainactivity.java

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please go through the tutorial that i have mentioned. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all @ZeeshanShabbir but I don't see FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() in your answer

Comment: I want to send this data to my server FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Comment: I have editted the answer again. Have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

After you create class mentioned in above answer, just create an object and pass the url as follow:

```
OkHttpAsync okHttpAsync = new OkHttpAsync();
okHttpAsync.execute("http://localhost/register.php");
```

This is what @Zeeshan mentioned in first line of his answer.

Thank You.